# How to add Splashscreen to finished game?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-fragmentactivity

I want to add a splash screen to finished game. In my Main Activity I don't want to change my layout act_main, just add a splash screen layout before this Activity. How I can do this?

Fragment of my ActMain:

```
        public class ActMain extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {               
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `android:windowBackground` to your main activity `theme` attribute in the `manifest` like this,  :-

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
```

this will populate the screen with the `drawable` before the layout is rendered and set.

But if you have a `appbar` on your mainactivity it would, you will need another activity for splash screen as the appbar may hinder your splash screen design , since you only have a single theme for the activity.

Check this [article](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857) will show you the right way to make splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a separate `SplashActivity` with its own layout or just custom window background

Comment: Another `<activity>` tag under `<application>` with launch intent flag

Answer (score 0):

Thx! Is worked.

```
SplashScreen.class

public class SplashScreen extends FragmentActivity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ActMain.class);
            startActivity(i);

            //close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```